# How to construct an object with arguments in c++

Tags: c++, constructor

I keep getting this error: `no matching function for call to 'Person::Person(const char [10])`
The class is in a separate cpp file. I can easily create an object when I have the constructor in the same cpp file. This is my code:

main.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Person.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Person p("hellooooo");
    return 0;
}
```

Person.h file

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H


class Person
{
    public:
        Person();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // PERSON_H
```

Person.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Person.h"

using namespace std;

Person::Person()
{
   cout << "this is the default constructor??";
}

Person::Person(string n)
{
   cout << n;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

you have to add declaration of second constructor in your `.h` file

```
#include <string>
class Person
{
    public:
        Person();
        Person(std::string);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, and +1. (Also, I edited the question... Terminology, terminology everywhere... :P)

Comment: +1, or change the constructor to `Person(const std::string& n = "This is the constructor") and just `cout << n;` in the body. Either way works.